# Replace a string in html code with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, replace

How do I replace a tag ( |mybackground| ) with another string ( an url )  in a block of html code using javascript?

I am working in a block in a wordpress site. I have a large html email template. So I want to get that, change the tag into an url, and then send it as emailcontent to a user. It has to be changed because every user will get his personalised image in it and they all have different names. But I want to use 1 base template (Actually I have a whole html emailtemplate with a lot more code but I just post a snippet here.)

```
<div id="emailcontent">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-image: url('|mybackground|');">

      ...some content...

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `td` an ID and use `document.getElementById("yourId").setAttribute("background", "[www.yourUrl.com]")`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not replace strings in HTML. It is very poor practice.

VML is [no longer supported by IE10+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801223(v=vs.85).aspx) so you can remove the code (it is even incomplete since you do not even have a v:textbox start ) - I fixed it but you can still remove it:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true">
    <v:fill type="frame" src="|mybackground|" position="0,0" />
  </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

---

***Instead do something like this.***

```js
$(function() {
  var card = "X", // where to get card from?
       $td = $("#emailcontent").find("td[background='|mybackground|']"),
       img = $("#"+card).attr('src');
  $td.attr("background",img);
  $td.attr("style",$td.attr("style").replace("|mybackground|",img));
});
```

```css
#X { display:none }
td { height:200px; width:200px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="emailcontent">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td background="|mybackground|" style="background-image: url('|mybackground|');">Here is an elephant</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr/>
  <img id="X" src="http://d5prcm06amy2t.cloudfront.net/mobile/mobile-hank04-shadow.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> To perform a global search and replace, either include the g switch in
>   the regular expression or if the first parameter is a string, include
>   g in the flags parameter.

So, even if this is dirty stuff, on this way should work:

```js
var find = '\\|mybackground\\|';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, $("#card").attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="emailcontent">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td background="|mybackground|" style="background-image: url('|mybackground|');">
  
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<img id="card" src="mysource">
```